# Powershell where clause filtering

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to filter services running in server using powershell script.But the syntax seems not in proper way

Script

Get-Service -ComputerName $ServerName |Where-Object **{$_.Name -like "DEX*" -or $_.Name -like "WORLD*"  -or $_.Name -like "Entr*"}**

the highlighted section is having the problem.Any help is well appreciated..

Comment: The first thing I see is that your example is missing the closing `}`. What errors and/or unexpected behavior are you seeing when you run this line?

Comment: } brace added.That was missed while adding.

Comment: It just fetches the services with Name -like "DEX*" other part is ignored

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `Get-Service` `Name` property match the short name of the service. Don't you need the `DisplayName` ?

```
Get-Service -ComputerName $ServerName |Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "DEX*" -or $_.DisplayName -like "WORLD*" -or $_.DisplayName -like "Entr*"}
```

Another thing, your services short or display names are really begining by **WORLD** or **Entr** ?

Comment: Yes JPBLanc display names are begining with World and Entr..Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Once you know you are looking for displayname, here is a shortest way :

```
 get-service -displayname DEX*,WORLD*,Entr*
```